# code igniter / php - concatenating two POST variables to form a new variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form where a user submits his member name, first and last. I want to combine these two and send them to the database as a member ID using code igniter's `url_title` functionality. In other words just making sure that it's all lower case, underscores, URL safe, etc. This is the code in my model, but in the database I'm getting a value of zero for the `memberID`:

```
$v_membername = $this->input->post('f_membername');
$v_memberlast = $this->input->post('f_memberlast');
$v_memberid = $v_membername + "_" + $v_memberlast;
$v_memberid = url_title($v_memberid, 'underscore');

$data = array(
    'member_name' => $v_membername,
    'member_last' => $v_memberlast,
    'member_id' => $v_memberid
);

$this->db->insert('members', $data);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? `membername` and `memberlast` submit to the DB just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP uses `.` to concat strings, not `+`.

```
$v_memberid = $v_membername . "_" . $v_memberlast;
```

Comment: doh. Thanks. Got stuck in javascript mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$v_memberid = $_POST['f_membername'].'_'.$_POST['f_memberlast'];
```

Comment: If you're using CodeIgniter, I suggest using `$this->input->post`, as it does XSS filtering and such.